# TS doesn't see types in my Svelte package

Tags: typescript, npm, svelte, sveltekit, .d.ts

I've created [a Svelte package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-plotly.js) from a SvelteKit project. The project has only one file: `/src/lib/Plot.svelte`, I packaged and published it using the following commands:

```sh
yarn package
cd package
yarn publish
```

The published package has a compiled `Plot.svelte` file and a type definitions file `Plot.svelte.d.ts`. However, if I import the package in another Svelte project, I get an error:

```
Cannot find module 'svelte-plotly.js' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

I can fix the error by going to `package/package.json` and adding `"types": "./Plot.svelte.d.ts"` there. However, this change will be overriden by the next `yarn package`. There has to be a better way to do this!

To sum up my question: **How do I make SvelteKit to export a package with type declarations correctly linked in package.json?**

Comment: Can you put it in the _root_ package file instead?

Comment: You're right, adding `"types": "./Plot.svelte.d.ts"` to the root package.json fixes the problem! However, it feels weird, as there is no `Plot.svelte.d.ts` file in the root directory. It feels more like a hack/walkaround than the intended way to make packages. But it does the job! :)